# Return values in parentheses with Python 2

Tags: python

I need to use Python 2 with my server. But the code below I use in my computer using Python 3, and is not working in version 2.
Anyone knows the conversion of the command below to Python 2? I need to return a value in parentheses.

Python 3:

```
    try:
        new = re.search(r'\([^)]*\)', value)
        new = str(new[0])
    except:
        return value
```

Python 2

```
????
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. I don't see anything that would make this code behave differently between 2 and 3, but `value` is undefined, so I can't say for sure. However, part of the problem might be the [bare `except`, which is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948581/4518341). Try making it as specific as possible, e.g. `except TypeError`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can add `,` in the end like

```py
import re

value = '5.2 (37.2)'
regex = '\([\d.]+\)'
ans = re.search(regex, value)
print(value[ans.start()+1:ans.end()-1] )
```

it will give

`37.2`

Comment: I have the string "5.2 (37.2)"
I need just the value in parentheses:
37.2

Comment: Like Jhonathan said, you're missing the point, but in any case, tuples work the same between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: sorry a misunderstanding in question. you can use it

Comment: import re

value = '5.2 (37.2)'
regex = '\([\d.]+\)'
ans = re.search(regex, value)
print(value[ans.start()+1:ans.end()-1] )
this will give `37.2`